# How to delete same named directory in same location using linux?

Tags: linux

Am unable to delete the same named directory in the same location .

```
[root@server paid]# ls -ld AFO*
drwxr-x--- 4 j133 jsftp 26 Aug 10 08:24 AFOS
drwx------ 2 j133 jsftp 72 Aug  9 12:47 AFOS
```

I need to delete the aug 9 created directory but am unable to delete it . Renaming and moving the folder also not worked as i expected .

Comment: there must be some unprintable character in dir name, otherwise better run fsck

Comment: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/linux-unix-examples-of-find-command-to-find-files-with-specific-sets-of-permissions

Answer (score 0):

this will just print some info. use `-delete` flag when the desired directory is actually the info

```
find -maxdepth 1 ! -perm -710 -type d -name 'AFO*' -print -exec stat {} +
```

edit: `-delete` won't work with `-maxdepth` but you can replace `stat` with `rm -r`

```
find -maxdepth 1 ! -perm -710 -type d -name 'AFO*' -print -exec rm -r {} +
```

Comment: that folders includes some sub folders too its not allowing to delete

Comment: replace `stat` with `rm` or whatever you want to do with